# How to use default output device as a source to record audio with AudioGraph?

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

In my UWP app I have the below code, that works with an input device (DeviceInformation), to record audio and to process this. I want to extend this, by also using the default output device instead of the mic. This basically means the app will analyze the audio going over the audio card and the speakers.

This is my code:

```
 AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media)
            {
                QuantumSizeSelectionMode = QuantumSizeSelectionMode.LowestLatency
            };

            CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);

            if (result.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
            {
                // Cannot create graph
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("AudioGraph Creation Error because {0}", result.Status.ToString()));
                return;
            }

            graph = result.Graph;

            // Create a device output node
            CreateAudioDeviceOutputNodeResult deviceOutputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
            if (deviceOutputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
            {
                return;
            }

            AudioDeviceOutputNode deviceOutputNode = deviceOutputNodeResult.DeviceOutputNode;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Device Output connection successfully created");


            // Create a device input node using the default audio input device
            CreateAudioDeviceInputNodeResult deviceInputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(MediaCategory.Other, graph.EncodingProperties, SelectedDevice);

            if (deviceInputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
            {
                // Cannot create device input node
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Audio Device Input unavailable because {0}", deviceInputNodeResult.Status.ToString()));

                return;
            }

            AudioDeviceInputNode deviceInputNode = deviceInputNodeResult.DeviceInputNode;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Device Input connection successfully created");


            frameOutputNode = graph.CreateFrameOutputNode();
            deviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(frameOutputNode);

            AudioFrameInputNode frameInputNode = graph.CreateFrameInputNode();
            frameInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(deviceOutputNode);
            //   frameInputNode.QuantumStarted += FrameInputNode_QuantumStarted;

            // Attach to QuantumStarted event in order to receive synchronous updates from audio graph (to capture incoming audio).
            graph.QuantumStarted += GraphOnQuantumProcessed;
```

How can I use the default **output** device in

```
CreateAudioDeviceInputNodeResult deviceInputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(MediaCategory.Other, graph.EncodingProperties, SelectedDevice);
```

Comment: This is already answered on msdn forum https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f50d21bc-61d7-4058-ba6c-4da6c9b90c95/route-media-audio-to-speakereven-if-headset-is-connect-uwp?forum=wpdevelop you can change output device even if headset and other device is connected

Comment: No, that's something different. I want to record/process the audio that goes over the sound card to the output (Speakers) instead of the microphone.

Comment: Are you want to record playback sound card sound https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615457/recording-capture-currently-playing-audio

Answer (score 1):

To get the current default audio output (Render) device in one line:

```cs
var defaultDevice = await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(MediaDevice.GetDefaultAudioRenderId(AudioDeviceRole.Default));
```

You can also get the default Capture device and listen to changed events for each with the [MediaDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Devices.MediaDevice?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-18362#Windows_Media_Devices_MediaDevice_DefaultAudioRenderDeviceChanged) class.

It would seem that you can't use a Render device as an input node to record system audio ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026841/using-audiorender-device-as-input-for-audiograph-uwp))