# Using AudioRender device as Input for AudioGraph UWP

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

I have a fully functional AudioGraph system in place for a realtime voice chat. You can select the AudioCapture and AudioRender devices before and during the chat however I'd also like to be able to use Audio from the AudioRender devices for input on the AudioCapture graphs. How can I go about that?

I currently have tried just selecting the device with the device Id however it gives the error:
 `"DeviceNotAvailable"`.

for

`CreateAudioDeviceInputNodeResult result = await ingraph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(MediaCategory.Media, nodesettings.EncodingProperties, selectedDevice);`

selectedDevice being

`selectedDevice = await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(InputDeviceID);`

Answer (score 0):

Derive from official document [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audiograph.createdeviceinputnodeasync#Windows_Media_Audio_AudioGraph_CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync_Windows_Media_Capture_MediaCategory_Windows_Media_MediaProperties_AudioEncodingProperties_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceInformation_) segment,

> Call `FindAllAsync`, passing in the value returned by `GetAudioCaptureSelector`, to get the list of DeviceInformation objects representing the **available** capture devices. For more information, see Audio graphs.

```
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformationCollection devices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(Windows.Media.Devices.MediaDevice.GetAudioRenderSelector());
```

For more please refer [**Audio graphs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs) document.

Comment: This just tells you how to select the device, it doesn't tell us much about the issue with setting a render device to an input node. I have this same problem. Valid `DeviceInformation` instance, same error message.